# Creating Input element and appending it to form with ngModel

Tags: html, angular

I have a select dropdown with its onChange event mapped to a function which should create an input element with ngModel along with other attributes, and append it to another element, like so:

```
<select class="form-control" id="addUsers" (change)='addProfession($event.target.value)'> 
    <option *ngFor='let profession of professions' [value]='profession.ProfessionTypeName'>
         {{ profession.ProfessionTypeName }}
     </option>
<div #addUsersProfessionsSelect></div>
```

Below you can finds the function bound to the select's change event:

```
addProfession(professionName: string) {
    let profession = new Profession(Profession.nameToIdMap[professionName], professionName);
    this.shouldDisplayProfessionsInputs = true;

    let professionInput = `<div>${profession.professionName}
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [id]='${profession.professionName}' name='${profession.professionName}'
          [(ngModel)]="newCampaign.users[${profession.professionTypeId}]"></div>`

    let safeHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(professionInput);
    let element = this.renderer.createElement(this.addUsersProfessionsSelect.nativeElement, 'div');
    this.renderer.setElementProperty(element, 'outerHTML', safeHTML);
}
```

addProfession does create and append the element, but it ignores all attributes. Here's the added input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [id]="Stylist" placeholder="Stylist"   
               name="Stylist" [(ngmodel)]="newCampaign.users[6]">
```

Do note the lowercase attribute names, and ignored brackets on the [id] attribute.

I'd love any help on this subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly manipulating the DOM, I pushed the new profession to an array on which I used an *ngFor and bound the data I needed to the iterator.